# How to map three collection using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried to map three collection using mongodb .I completed two collection but another collection I cant map how to achieve it any one give example code.

**group_promotion**

```
[{

"id":1,
"group_name":"latest",  
 products:[6,7,8]

}]
```

**product**

```
[{

"id":6,  
"produc_namme":"bourbon",
"category_id": 20

}]
```

**Category**

```
[{

"id":20,
"category_name":"beer"

}]
```

**Mapping code**

```
db.group_promoton.aggregate([{$lookup :  
{  
from:"product",  
localfield:"products",  
foreignField:'id',  
as:products  
}}])
```

**I got output**

```
[{

"id":1,
"group_name":"latest",  
 products:[{
"id":6,  
"produc_namme":"bourbon",
"category_id": 20
}]

}]
```

**Excepted output**

```
[{

"id":1,  
"group_name":"latest",    
 products:[{  
"id":6,    
"produc_namme":"bourbon",  
"category_nmae":"beer"  
}]

}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here give the below query a try:

```
db.getCollection("group_promotion").aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "product",
        localField: "products",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "products"
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$products" },
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Category",
        localField: "products.category_id",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "category"
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$category" },
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$id', "group_name": { $first: "$group_name" }, "products": {
            $push: {
                "id": "$products.id", "produc_namme": "$products.produc_namme", "category_nmae": "$category.category_name"
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

**Note:**

- You can always use `$lookup` on the `dotted` property of an array (*as explained in the above query for `Category` collection*).
- Here i am using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to deconstruct the arrays (*i.e. products and category*) and later grouping them to create the result. I have used [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html) to satisfy the [$group accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) policy and display the first value.